# Null controllability of the heat equation with an internal control (for positive solutions)

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, oc.optimization-and-control, parabolic-pde

Let $\Omega$ a bounded open regular subset of $R^N$ and $\omega$ an open subset such that $\omega \subset \Omega$. Let $T >0$.
Let $y_0$ in $L^2(\Omega)$.
It's a well-known fact in the theory of control of PDE's that there exists $u \in L^2((0,T) \times \Omega )$ such that the solution of the Cauchy-problem (Dirichlet conditions or Neumann conditions for example)
$$ \partial_t y - \Delta y = u 1_{\omega},\quad y(0,\cdot)= y0$$
satisfies $y(T,\cdot)=0$.

My question is : If we suppose that $y_0 \geq 0$ almost everywhere, can we find $h \in L^2((0,T) \times \Omega)$ such that the solution of the Cauchy problem (Dirichlet conditions or Neumann conditions for example) $$ \partial_t y - \Delta y = h 1_{\omega},\quad y(0,\cdot)= y0$$ satisfies $y \geq 0$ almost everywhere and $y(T,\cdot) =0$ ?

Comment: I had problems parsing the question, so I took the liberty of editing it a bit. Also, I put $h1_\omega$ on the right hand side of the last equation and hope, that this is correct.

Comment: I'm not convinced by your first claim. Could you provide some details how you show it (using control theory)? In particular whtat if $y_0$ is a (Dirichlet) eigenfunction of $\Delta$ on $\Omega$ and any forcing term restricted to $\omega$ will have modes other than $y_0$?

Comment: While still not completely clear what the problem is, I now suspect your conjecture does not hold. Let the initial data $y_0$ be 0 on $\omega$, but have some positive smooth bumps in $\Omega-\omega$. Suppose $y\ge0$ on $\omega\times[0,T]$. Then evaluating your inhomogeneous heat equation at time 0 shows that $h\ge0$ on $\omega$. Then a comparison to the solution to the homogeneous heat equation with the same initial data shows that $y>0$ everywhere on $\Omega\times[0,T]$, which contradicts $y(T,\cdot)=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the initial problem, I forgot that the term of control (u for the first equation and h for the second equation) depends of time... I have edited the question.

Comment: Fan Zheng, Does your proof always word in the case where the control is non autonomous ? Particularly, I don't understand the fact that the control $h$ is positive. I will provide some details of the first claim in the evening (it was proved in 1995 and in 1996).

Comment: @kitaextraire I thought the control was autonomous, and if it is nonautonomous, could you just fix some nonnegative boundary values on $\partial\omega$, solve the homogeneous heat equation in $\Omega-\omega$, extend the solution $u$ to a nonnegative function on the whole of $\Omega$, and then let $h=\partial_t u-\Delta u$? I could be missing something as this problem now looks too underdetermined for me.